# boost for windows, first time use

Tags: boost

i just downloaded boost 1_45_0 for windows.  i have vc++6 installed on my windows 7 64bit pc.  in the windows introduction, i'm told to try to compile a small lambda program.
i placed boost in the root of c:, i have c:\boost\boost_1_45_0.  i added "c:\boost\boost_1_45_0" to my "include" environment variable in the windows advanced system settings

what else do i need to do before i c

when i try to compile at the command prompt, i get the following:
C:\test\boost>cl /EHsc /I c:\boost\boost_1_45_0 boost.cpp
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 12.00.8804 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-1998. All rights reserved.

boost.cpp
c:\boost\boost_1_45_0\boost/config/suffix.hpp(596) : error C2039: 'typeinfo' : i
s not a member of '`global namespace''
c:\boost\boost_1_45_0\boost/config/suffix.hpp(596) : error C2873: 'typeinfo' : s
ymbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
c:\boost\boost_1_45_0\boost/mpl/aux_/yes_no.hpp(56) : fatal error C1506: unrecov
erable block scoping error

Answer (score 0):

You are using a compiler that is now 12 years old, and boost doesn't support it. You'll need VS.Net 2003 at a [minimum](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_35_0), but I'd strongly recommend VS2008 or VS2010.  There is a free '[express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/)' version of VS2010.  Unless you have a **very** specific need to use VC++6 I would ditch it now.